# PHP PDO Exception vs Exception Strangeness

Tags: php, database, exception, pdo

This seems really weird. The class below works fine, and displays `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'` with the wrong password, as I'd expect.

However, if I replace `catch{Eception...` with `catch{Exception...` then no error is displayed, in spite of wrong password.

I've tried

```
$class_methods = get_class_methods(new Eception);

foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) {
    echo "$method_name\n";
}
```

and the class doesn't exist, so why does it work in my Database class when  `Exception` doesn't?

```
<?php
class Database{
    private $host   = 'localhost';
    private $user   = 'root';
    private $pass   = 'wrong_password';
    private $dbname     = 'blog';

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct(){
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => TRUE,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
        // Create new PDO
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch(Eception $e){ // weird behaviour with Exception vs Eception
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you are doing when you catch an exception is this:

```
$this->error = $e->getMessage();
```

You don't seem to be displaying it so when you actually catch the exception, nothing will be displayed and your script will continue.

When you use a non-existing class (`Eception`, etc.), you are not catching anything as this is not the kind of exception that is thrown. So your script halts and the default exception message is shown:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'
             ^^^^^^^^ You did not catch the exception in your code, 
                      you see the default php exception handler
```

Comment: OK, so I've changed Eception to Exception and echoed `$e->getMessage()`. Now I have a nice clean error message. Thanks.

Comment: @Robin you shouldn't echo $e->getMessage() and shouldn't have a nice clean error message. You're  not the sole user of your site.

Comment: @Robin For debugging it is fine, just don't show this message to users on a live site, log it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You just misunderstood the error message. It says '*Uncaught exception*' which, as you can tell, means your exception **weren't caugnt.** Which in turn is quite logical, as you were looking for Eception while Exception were thrown.

While with a proper exception name it gets caught, and thus there is no uncaught exception error to be thrown.

And of course your code remains silent as there is no action to be taken in case of error. This is why it is advised not to catch your errors right in place but let them bubble up tp the appropriate handler.

There is also one important thing about exceptions nobody really understands.

Exceptions are caught in subordinations. Means you can use a parent exception to catch all the inherited exceptions. For example, if there is a class

- `Exception` which is a parent to

  - `RuntimeException` which is a parent to

    - `PDOException`,

then you can use either to catch PDO errors.

But you cannot catch an exception which is not subordinate to a given one.

Therefore, with `catch(Eception $e)` you can catch only `Eception` or its subordinates, which will make it impossible to use with PDO, no matter whether it exists or not.

Note that your class suffer from many other errors. You can read about them in my article, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#errors). Having $stmt as a Database class property is a most disastrous one.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this. I got my code from a free PHP OOP course online. I will read your article and try to assimilate.

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions you got.